# bootstrap Popover inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I m displaying a popver inside the modal i can hide it on close but unable to hide it while clicking out side the modal. I try to hide it by on close which is fine. the code is here

```
$('.close, .close-button').click(function(){
    $(".popover.bottom").css('display', 'none');
});
```

I tried to hide by clicking out side the modal but it is hide when I click inside the modal.

```
$("#myModal").click(function(){
    if(($("#myModal").attr('aria-hidden')) == 'false'){
        $(".popover.bottom").not('.modal-content').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: if condition works or not?

Comment: yes if condition is working the pop even i Click inside the modal

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myModal").click(function(){

    if(!$("#myModal").attr('aria-hidden')){

        $(".popover.bottom").not('.modal-content').hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: all your code is right . then what is the reason it won't work i don't know

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Issue. Could you try this instead? Replace your id/class from bootstrap.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
            //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
            //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }
        });
 });
```

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(".popover.bottom").css('display', 'none');
});
```